# Boost Python import fails, symbol of wrapped class not defined

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have a problem using boost python in my current project. When I try to import the generated module in python 3.6 the following error shows: ImportError: PythonTrackWrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18PythonTrackWrapperD1Ev where PythonTrackWrapper is the class I want to wrap for use in Python. I cannot track down the error and would appreciate your help!

PythonTrackWrapper.cpp:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

PythonTrackWrapper::PythonTrackWrapper(std::vector<boost::tuple<double, double>>& left, std::vector<boost::tuple<double, double>>& right, boost::tuple<double, double>& currentPose){

    std::vector<double> X, Y;

    produceTrack(left, right, currentPose, X, Y);

    track = Track(X, Y);

}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonTrackWrapper)
{

    class_<PythonTrackWrapper>("PythonTrackWrapper", init<std::vector<boost::tuple<double, double>>&, std::vector<boost::tuple<double, double>>&, boost::tuple<double, double>&>())
            .def("get_progress_on_track", &PythonTrackWrapper::getProgressOntrack);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Spline)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python3 REQUIRED)

find_package(Python3 3.6 REQUIRED)

...

add_library(PythonTrackWrapper SHARED PythonTrackWrapper.cpp)
set_target_properties(PythonTrackWrapper PROPERTIES SUFFIX .so)
set_target_properties(PythonTrackWrapper PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

target_link_libraries(PythonTrackWrapper Spline boost_python3 ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${Python3_LIBRARIES})
```

This is the code I think is most likely to contain errors pertaining to the problem, if you think the cause might lay elsewhere I'd be happy to post the rest.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to increase chances that somebody helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, the issues was that I had a destructor defined in my .h file, which I then however did not implement. Hope that helps someone.